# Difference between yarn, npm and npx

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx, yarn-v2

I have been researching about this over and over. What is the difference between yarn, npm and npx in the context of creating react apps

I have read a lot of articles on it yet had no solid explanation to it. I'm trying to use these separately to see if there are different features in them but I see nothing

Comment: I've seen this question before and the Cliff Notes is npm is more widely used because it comes pre-packaged and thus has larger support, but yarn is evidently more efficient  performance wise, but broader support is more limited due to the less current useage.

Comment: [npx is part of npm.](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx) Yarn is a _different_ package manager.

Comment: Ignoring npx for now, because it's not the same kind of thing as npm or yarn, the answer to this question depends on which day you ask the question. Just pick one. If you're new, I would just pick npm initially. Once you know more, maybe consider yarn or pnpm or <fill in the gap> if it's an optimization for your use case.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

NPM, NPX, and Yarn are all JavaScript package managers.
Here are some differences between them:
NPM
The default package manager for Node.js. NPM is used to download JavaScript packages from the Node Package Manager. NPM is also used to install Node packages. NPM is more widely used because it comes pre-packaged and has larger support.
NPX
NPX is used to execute JavaScript packages downloaded from the Node Package Manager. NPX allows running packages without installation. NPX is not installed in computers if NPM has been installed prior to 5.2.0.
Yarn
Yarn is a package manager that also functions as a project manager. Yarn provides enhanced performance and additional features compared to NPM. Yarn is more efficient than NPM, but has more limited support due to less current usage.
The choice between NPM, NPX, and Yarn depends on project requirements, performance needs, and personal preference.

Comment: AI generated content is [currently banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/20153035) on Stack Overflow. Please read the [AI Policy](/help/ai-policy) for more information.

Comment: npx is a package runner, not a package manager. Specifically, it's npm's package runner.